# np.array(song).shape[0] > 50 means

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to understand the one of program and its taking midi files as input and midiToNoteStateMatrix is coverting the song into matrix. But i am not able to understand this line :

```
if np.array(song).shape[0] > 50:
```

what is the meaning of this line ?

```
def get_songs(path):
        files = glob.glob('{}/*.mid*'.format(path))
        songs = []
        for f in tqdm(files):
            try:
                song = np.array(midi_manipulation.midiToNoteStateMatrix(f))
                if np.array(song).shape[0] > 50:
                    songs.append(song)
            except Exception as e:
                raise e           
        return songs

    songs = get_songs('Pop_Music_Midi') 
    print ("{} songs processed".format(len(songs)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't you here filter the songs that have more tha 50 notes?

Comment: but what is shape[0] means ?

Comment: It means the *number* of rows (or well in a highly dimensional matrix the length of the first dimension).

Comment: You might need to look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html), `shape` will return the list of all the dimensions (by dimension I mean size of it), consequently `shape[0]` will return only the first dimension

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to answer.... because song.shape has a format...supposing that `song.shape` prints something with format (n,m) it means..the variable `song` is a 2d array or matrix with n rows and m columns... so `song.shape[0]` will return the first argument of (n,m) wich is the number of rows.... so imagining the song has n number of lines and each line has m words... `song.shape[0]` means check if the song has more than 50 lines